# createAsyncThunk: error upon calling endpoint is not triggering .rejected

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying out '@reduxjs/toolkit' v1.4.0

I have been trying out error handling. Although I can get the error from the endpoint:

```
{
  "code": "missing_access_key",
  "message": "You have not supplied an API Access Key. [Required format: access_key=YOUR_ACCESS_KEY]"
}
```

I am unable to get it to trigger:

```
    builder.addCase(fetchUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
      // FIXME: rejected not being called on error
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.error.message
    })
```

I keep looking at the docs and have even tried rejectWithValue. The 'pending' and 'fulfilled' conditions are called upon success, but I can't seem to trigger 'rejected'. I have tried try/catch blocks as well. Would be very grateful if anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/fetchUsers',
  async (users: Users) => {
    const response: any = await fetch(
      `${ENDPOINTS.USERS_SOURCE}tickers/search=${answers.ticker}&access_key=${process.env.MARKET_WATCH_API_KEY}&limit=${RESULTS_LIMIT}`
    )

    return response.data
  }
)

type SliceState = {
  error?: null | string
  loading: boolean
  data: null | SingleUser
  selectedData: null | SingleUser
}

// First approach: define the initial state using that type
const initialState: SliceState = {
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  data: null,
}

export const UsersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'Users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearUsers: (state) => {
      state.data = null
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchUsers.pending, (state) => {
      state.data = null
      state.loading = true
    })
    builder.addCase(fetchUsers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.data = action.payload
    })
    builder.addCase(fetchUsers.rejected, (state, action) => {
      // FIXME: rejected not being called on error
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.error.message
    })
  },
})

export const { clearUsers } = UsersSlice.actions

export default UsersSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fetch()` method returns a Promise that resolves regardless of whether the request is successful, unless there's a network error. In other words, the Promise isn't rejected even when the response has an HTTP 400 or 500 status code.

To ensure the `fetchUsers.rejected` reducer is called in this case, you should check [Response.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) after the Promise resolves as in this minimal example:

```js
const response = await fetch(url)

if (!response.ok) {
  // throw appropriate error
}

...
```

See [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! Have added the following code:


`if (response.error) return Promise.reject(response.error)`